What's the density of Proxima Centauri's photosphere?
Proxima Centauri is a red dwarf much denser (33X on average) than the sun. Yet I'm not finding anything about Proxima Centauri's photosphere. The Sun's photosphere is only 0.2 g/m3 (1/10,000th of sea level air. So I'm wondering about Proxima Centauri's photosphere. Is it a vacuum like the sun's photosphere? Or is it dense? I'm wondering in comparison to sea level air in g/m3. The star should be near enough for us to determine that.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri ;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun

the Sun's photosphere is not a vacuum.  The density you give is somewhater denser than the atompshere of Triton, and haze and effects of wind have been detected on Triton.

Interesting info, but not really the purpose of my question. I was wondering about Proxima's photosphere relative to sea level air (or to hydrogen gas's standard density).
